# How to Disable ENTER Key Press for submit button when using Blazor <InputText>

Tags: blazor, keypress, .net-5, preventdefault, blazor-editform

I can't seem to find a way how to disable the enter key in a `<button type="submit">` wrapped inside an `<EditForm>`.

The problem is that at any blazor `<InputText>` control, when a user presses the ENTER key, blazor activates the validation and submit process.

I also tried using `<button type="submit" @onkeypress="@KeyHandler" @onkeypress:preventdefault>` but it does not work, the form still proceeds to validate and submits.

More specifically inside my `<EditForm>` I am calling a modal dialog that contains an `<InputText>` for searching items, and every time ENTER is pressed to perform the search, the form gets validated and submitted in the background :(

Please help

Comment: blazor-editform is a bit of an obscure Tag with few watchers.  Try blazor if you have another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<InputText @bind-Value="_model.Value" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
<input @bind-value="_model.Value" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
```

credit to @dustysilicon.

Here's my Test Page:

```cs
@page "/Editor"
<h3>EditForm</h3>

<EditForm EditContext="this._editContext" OnSubmit="SubmitForm">
    <div class="p-2">
        No Enter: <InputText @bind-Value="_model.SelectValue" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        No Enter: <input type="number" @bind-value="_model.Value" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        Enter: <input @bind-value="_model.SelectValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
<div class="m-2 p-2">Value: @_model.Value</div>
<div class="m-2 p-2">@message</div>

@code {

    public class Model
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string SelectValue { get; set; }
    }

    private string message;
    Model _model = new Model();

    EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(_model);
    }

    void SubmitForm()
    {
        message = $"Form Submitted at :{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @MrCakaShaunCurtis, thank you very much for the reply..I tried your suggestion, but Blazor does not recognize event.keyCode!=13 :( also I did try handling the Enter key in the KeyHandler function..but still it pushes the Enter key even after I handled it...

Comment: @GAC - I've added the page I used to test what I suggested.   I ran it in Server Mode.  The only enter that submits the form is when focus is in the third input.  Try it.

Comment: Hi @MrCakaShaunCurtis, sorry for very late reply...I've tried everything I just can't seem to make this particular code 'onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"' work... :( but thank you very much for the response and the help...I ended up using EditContext and manually triggering the validation method on button click with type button instead of type submit....again thank you thank you!!!!